# HTTPS POST request using VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, post, https

I use "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" to send HTTP POST requests from VBA in Excel.
But I could not manage to do it for HTTPS, as I received an SSL certificate error.

What VBA code would you use to negotiate an SSL connection to a website from VBA in Excel ?

Comment: Could you post some code please? Also, is "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" a COM component? where to find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *WinHttpRequest* object has a *SetClientCertificate* method. Try this code example taken from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384055(VS.85).aspx) (I tried to adapt  it for VBA):

```
' Instantiate a WinHttpRequest object. '
Dim HttpReq as new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

' Open an HTTP connection. '
HttpReq.Open("GET", "https://www.test.com/", false)

' Select a client certificate. '
HttpReq.SetClientCertificate("LOCAL_MACHINE\Personal\My Certificate")

' Send the HTTP Request. '
HttpReq.Send()
```

Answer (score 2):

While I have not used the COM component (WinHttpRequest), it seems you need a call to [SetClientCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384055(VS.85).aspx)  prior to calling send, as per the link.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation (send a http request from a VBA in Excel); I created three objects:

```
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```

-- for the http request class, and

```
Set fsobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set txtobj = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\PKCERT.PEM")
```

-- to get into a variable the certificate contents, to pass it to `HttpReq.SetClientCertificate`,

```
certificate_data = txtobj.ReadAll
HttpReq.SetClientCertificate (certificate_content)
```

So I can send the request including its public key certificate, as usual,

```
HttpReq.Send
```

P.S. I found a script at http://www.808.dk/?code-simplewinhttprequest -- it worked fine in my case, hope in yours too.